# NextJs Api Folder as backend?

Tags: node.js, next.js, backend

i was wondering nextjs creates a folder called api with a hello.js when i do localhost:3000/hello in the browser i get a hello world back i was wondering if i can make this hello.js so that you can log in so a simple request and see if the password is correct to send a token back. now to my actual question:

how secure is it to use this hello.js or the api folder of nexztjs as a backend for a login system i am fairly new to this topic and am not sure if a hacker can refactor this hello.js for example and see / manipulate my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### I asked the same thing when I was starting

It seems like it isn't secure, but it is when you deploy your project to Vercel *which I am assuming you will use as it is the recommended method and you are new to this* Vercel deploys your API folder exclusively to the back end so none of the code in the api folder is exposed to the client. Additionally, your `getServerSideProps()` and `getStaticProps()` functions are also not exposed to the client and totally secure. This is all of course as long as you are using industry standards and secure methods of verification like JWT web token for example